# getText() not working in java for no reason

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, odbc

here is my code, getText() is not returning getting text from the JTextField. My Database has only two colomns, `MovieName` & `AirDate` & System DSN is `movieDSN`.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class MovieReminder implements ActionListener{
    //Public members of class
    JFrame frame= new JFrame("Add Movie");
    JPanel moviePane=new JPanel();
    JButton button=new JButton("Add Movie Time");
        JTextField movieName;
        JTextField airDate= new JTextField(15);
        Statement st;
        Connection con;
        String url;
        String sql;
                         String tmpMovieName;
                 String tmpairDate=airDate.getText();

    //GUI method of class making it public to access out side from class as well
    public void initGUI(){
        //adding action listener to our button & its class will be over-ridden at the end
        button.addActionListener(this);
        moviePane.add(new JLabel("Movie Name"));
                movieName=new JTextField(15);
                moviePane.add(movieName);
                tmpMovieName=movieName.getText();

                moviePane.add(new JLabel ("Air Date"));
                moviePane.add(airDate);
                moviePane.add(button);
                frame.add(moviePane);
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

        //sql method
        public void addMovie(){
            try{
                //loading Driver
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                //Making Connection
                String url="jdbc:odbc:movieDSN";
                 con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                //Creating Statement
                 st=con.createStatement();
                //sql Query to insert record

                 //sql="INSERT INTO movieTime (MovieName,AirDate) VALUES ( '"+movieName.getText()+"','"+airDate.getText()+"' ) ";
                 sql="INSERT INTO movieTime (MovieName,AirDate) VALUES ( '"+tmpMovieName+"','"+tmpairDate+"' ) ";

            }catch(Exception sqlex){
            System.out.println(sqlex);
            }
        }



    //constructor of main class
    MovieReminder(){
        initGUI();
                addMovie();
    }
    //overriding action performed method for our functions
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            try {
                st.executeUpdate(sql);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Value Added "+tmpMovieName);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
    MovieReminder myObject=new MovieReminder();
    }


}//end movieReminder class
```

Comment: double negative ... not working for no reason....to a programmer = working :)

Comment: @JoshEngelsma this isn't a double negative as working and reason are separate contexts which are having negative applied to them i.e. !working && !reason

Comment: If this program were not working, then clearly there is a reason it is not working. There is not no reason it is not working because if there were no reason it was not working then it would be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I can see
you aren't initializing MovieName.

```
movieName=new JTextField(15);
moviePane.add(movieName);
tmpMovieName=movieName.getText();
```

MovieName is an empty JTextField

you should try to set

```
tmpMovieName=movieName.getText();
```

in your actionperformed method

do it before you call your sql statement
and as well
your sql statement should be updated when you get the text from your jtextfield

Answer (score 1):

You have put code to get text at wrong place, Try putting your code in `actionPerformed`:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        try {
            tmpMovieName=movieName.getText();    //Put your code here
            System.out.println("tmpMovieName:"+tmpMovieName);
            st.executeUpdate(sql);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Value Added "+tmpMovieName);
}
```

You should build your query in action event. and try using `PreparedStatements` with placeholers to avoid `sql injection`.

Answer (score 1):

its a `illegal forward reference`.. you can not use `gettext()` in declaration portion..

So write like this.,

```
 public void addMovie()
 {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String url="jdbc:odbc:movieDSN";
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            st=con.createStatement();
            String tmpairDate=airDate.getText();
            sql="INSERT INTO movieTime (MovieName,AirDate) VALUES ( '"+tmpMovieName+"','"+tmpairDate+"' ) ";

        }catch(Exception sqlex)
        {
            System.out.println(sqlex);
        }
 }
```

Thanks...